# Finite amount of primes in sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I want to prove that there is infinite growing sequence $a_1, a_2,  \ldots,$ where for every integer $k \geq 0$, sequence $a_1 + k, a_2 + k, a_3 + k \ldots$ contains only finite amount of primes

Comment: $a_n=n!+2$ will do.

Comment: So, any thoughts about the situation, Martin?

Answer (score 2):

[Comment becomes answer]

Let $a_n=n!+2$ for $n=1,2,\dots$. Then for any $k\ge0$, and any $n\ge k+2$, we see that $k+2$ is a proper divisor of $a_n+k=n!+k+2$, since $k+2$ divides $n!$. Thus, the sequence $a_n+k$, $n=1,2,\dots$, contains at most $k+1$ primes.